# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object

Tags: php, sql, json, cocoa, swift2

The purpose of this code is to send data to a SQL database using PHP script. 
But when I try to run it I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

This is my code:

```
// Send userdata to server side
let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/userRegister.php");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myURL!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

// Create the task and execute it

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
data,response, error in

    if error != nil{
    print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    var err: NSError?

    do
    {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {

            var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            print("result: \(resultValue)")

            var isUserRegisterd:Bool = false;
            if(resultValue=="Success")
            {
                isUserRegisterd = true
            }

            var messageToDisplay: String = (parseJSON["message"] as? String)!

            if(!isUserRegisterd)
            {
                messageToDisplay = (parseJSON["message"] as? String)!
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Oké", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
                    action in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
                }
                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
            });
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        print(error)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: BTW, the `var err: NSError?` line is not needed. Also, that `messageToDisplay` logic probably isn't quite right (e.g. it will crash if `parseJSON` doesn't contain a value with a key of `message`). But, before you worry about these things, look at the `data` and `response` below and figure out why you didn't get the JSON response you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

That error generally means that the `NSData` doesn't contain valid JSON.

You should look at the `response` and the string representation of the `data` because if the server encountered a problem, it most likely would have returned a `statusCode` in the `NSHTTPURLResponse` (where `200` means that everything was OK, [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) describes what the other error codes mean) and the `NSData` likely contains HTML or text describing the nature of the problem:

```
do {
    // your code where you `try` parsing the JSON response goes here
} catch {
    print(error)

    if data != nil {
        let string = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(string)
    }

    print(response)
}
```

When you look at the `NSURLResponse` and `NSData` objects, you will you be far more likely to diagnose the problem.

--

By the way, I might advise specifying the `Content-Type` of the request. Also, I'd suggest percent-escaping the email address and password. The latter is important because if the values contain special characters (e.g. `+` and `&` are notable problems), the data will not be processed correctly by the server.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/userRegister.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let encodedEmail = userEmail.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormUrlencoded()
let encodedPassword = userPassword.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormUrlencoded()
let postString = "email=\(encodedEmail)&password=\(encodedPassword)"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Where

```
extension String {

    /// Percent escape value to be added to a HTTP request
    ///
    /// This percent-escapes all characters besize the alphanumeric character set and "-", ".", "_", and "*".
    /// This will also replace spaces with the "+" character as outlined in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded spec:
    ///
    /// http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm
    ///
    /// - returns: Return percent escaped string.

    func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormUrlencoded() -> String? {
        let allowedCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._* ")

        return stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedCharacters)?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can build the character set of allowed characters by starting with `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`, but you still have to remove a few characters as it will otherwise that allows certain characters pass unescaped (e.g. `+`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912606/1271826.

Or you could use a framework like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) which takes care of these details for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even the following code was causing this error by appending extra // slashes at the beginning of the output.

```
$arr = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Your message goes here!");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The reason was that these extra characters were being printed in other file that I included to this file.