# how to http post special chars in swift

Tags: php, swift

I'm using the following to post an email and password to my server (php script). The problem I'm having is the password contains a special char (specifically the `&` symbol) which seems to be getting stripped. I presume because it thinks its separating variables being passed. How can I pass this char without it stripping it?

```
let myURL = NSURL(string: "my script url here")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let postString = "email=\(userEmailText)&password=\(userPasswordText)"

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be wary of using `NSURLComponents` because the `NSURLQueryItem` might percent-escape the character in question, the `&`, it doesn't percent-escape the `+` character (which PHP will interpret as a space in conformance with the [W3C Specification for `x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm)). As [the `queryItems` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents/1407752-queryitems) says:

> **Note**
>
> [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) specifies which characters must be percent-encoded in the query component of a URL, but not how those characters should be interpreted. The use of delimited key-value pairs is a common convention, but isn't standardized by a specification. Therefore, you may encounter interoperability problems with other implementations that follow this convention.
>
> One notable example of potential interoperability problems is how the plus sign (`+`) character is handled:
>
> According to RFC 3986, the plus sign is a valid character within a query, and doesn't need to be percent-encoded. However, according to the [W3C recommendations for URI addressing](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html), the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space within a query string (for example, `?greeting=hello+world`).

This leaves a few alternatives for percent escaping the values you add to the query of the URL yourself if your value might include a `+` character:

1. You can build your own `CharacterSet` of characters to be escaped and then use `addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue` in Swift 3:

   ```
   extension String {

       /// Returns a new string made from the `String` by replacing all characters not in the unreserved
       /// character set (as defined by RFC3986) with percent encoded characters.

       func addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue() -> String? {
           let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.urlQueryValueAllowed()
           return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)
       }

   }

   extension CharacterSet {

       /// Returns the character set for characters allowed in the individual parameters within a query URL component.
       ///
       /// The query component of a URL is the component immediately following a question mark (?).
       /// For example, in the URL `http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1#jumpLink`, the query
       /// component is `key1=value1`. The individual parameters of that query would be the key `key1`
       /// and its associated value `value1`.
       ///
       /// According to RFC 3986, the set of unreserved characters includes
       ///
       /// `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`
       ///
       /// In section 3.4 of the RFC, it further recommends adding `/` and `?` to the list of unescaped characters
       /// for the sake of compatibility with some erroneous implementations, so this routine also allows those
       /// to pass unescaped.


       static func urlQueryValueAllowed() -> CharacterSet {
           return CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~/?")
       }

   }
   ```
2. Alamofire takes a similar approach, but approaches this from the other direction, namely grabbing the `.urlQueryAllowed` character set (which is close, but not quite right), and takes out reserved characters identified in RFC 3986. In Swift 3:

   ```
   /// Returns a percent-escaped string following RFC 3986 for a query string key or value.
   ///
   /// RFC 3986 states that the following characters are "reserved" characters.
   ///
   /// - General Delimiters: ":", "#", "[", "]", "@", "?", "/"
   /// - Sub-Delimiters: "!", "$", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", ";", "="
   ///
   /// In RFC 3986 - Section 3.4, it states that the "?" and "/" characters should not be escaped to allow
   /// query strings to include a URL. Therefore, all "reserved" characters with the exception of "?" and "/"
   /// should be percent-escaped in the query string.
   ///
   /// - parameter string: The string to be percent-escaped.
   ///
   /// - returns: The percent-escaped string.
   public func escape(_ string: String) -> String {
       let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
       let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

       var allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
       allowedCharacterSet.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")

       var escaped = ""

       //==========================================================================================================
       //
       //  Batching is required for escaping due to an internal bug in iOS 8.1 and 8.2. Encoding more than a few
       //  hundred Chinese characters causes various malloc error crashes. To avoid this issue until iOS 8 is no
       //  longer supported, batching MUST be used for encoding. This introduces roughly a 20% overhead. For more
       //  info, please refer to:
       //
       //      - https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/206
       //
       //==========================================================================================================
       if #available(iOS 8.3, *) {
           escaped = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) ?? string
       } else {
           let batchSize = 50
           var index = string.startIndex

           while index != string.endIndex {
               let startIndex = index
               let endIndex = string.index(index, offsetBy: batchSize, limitedBy: string.endIndex) ?? string.endIndex
               let range = startIndex..<endIndex

               let substring = string.substring(with: range)

               escaped += substring.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) ?? substring

               index = endIndex
           }
       }

       return escaped
   }
   ```

You could then use the above to percent escape the key and the value in the body of the request, for example:

```
let parameters = ["email" : email, "password" : password]
request.httpBody = parameters
    .map { (key, value) in
        let escapedKey = key.addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue()!
        let escapedValue = value.addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue()!
        return "\(escapedKey)=\(escapedValue)"
    }
    .joined(separator: "&")
    .data(using: .utf8)
```

---

For Swift 2 renditions of the above, see the [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35912606/2).

Answer (score 0):

You need to percent escape the password before adding it to the URL. Better yet, use NSURLComponents to build your URL and add a query string.

Comment: `NSURLComponents` lets characters like `+` pass unescaped.

Comment: It's intentional. The [documentation for `NSURLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcomponents/1407752-queryitems?changes=latest_minor) says "One notable example of potential interoperability problems is how the plus sign (`+`) character is handled ... you may need to preemptively percent-encode the plus sign character." But if you preemptively percent encode, when you pass it to `URLQueryItem`, it will then incorrectly percent encode the `%` of the percent encoded `+` sequence! Seriously limits usefulness of `NSURLComponents`, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code you can try in a playground.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var n = NSURLComponents()

let s = "blah"
// Note that the values here should not be % encoded
let item1 = NSURLQueryItem(name: "password1", value: "ab%&")
let item2 = NSURLQueryItem(name: "password2", value: "ab%&%#$%^&*(")

n.queryItems = [item1, item2]

n.URL?.query

n.queryItems?.count

n.queryItems![0].name
n.queryItems![0].value

n.queryItems![1].name
n.queryItems![1].value

n.URL
```

Comment: Annoyingly, `NSURLQueryItem` lets certain special characters pass unescaped (e.g. `+`).