# iOS swift post request with binary body

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest, urlrequest

I want to make a POST request from iOS (swift3) which passes a chunk of raw bytes as the body. I had done some experimenting which made me thought the following worked:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://bla/foo/bar")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = Data(hex: "600DF00D")
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    "DATA \(data ?? Data()) RESPONSE \(response) ERROR \(error)".print()
}
task.resume()
```

Didn't know it was a problem until I tried sending something simple like a single 0xF0. At which point my tornado server started complaining that I was sending it

```
WARNING:tornado.general:Invalid x-www-form-urlencoded body: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

Am I just supposed to set some header somehow? Or is there something different I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two common solutions are:

1. Your error message tells us that the web service is expecting a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request (e.g. `key=value`) and in for the `value`, you can perform a base-64 encoding of the binary payload.

   Unfortunately, base-64 strings still need to be percent escaped (because web servers generally parse `+` characters as spaces), so you have to do something like:

   ```
   let base64Encoded = data
       .base64EncodedString(options: [])
       .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)!
       .data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

   var body = "key=".data(using: .utf8)!
   body.append(base64Encoded)

   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
   request.httpBody = body
   request.httpMethod = "POST"
   request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
       guard error == nil else {
           print(error!)
           return
       }

       ...
   }
   task.resume()
   ```

   Where:

   ```
   extension CharacterSet {
       static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
           let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
           let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

           var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
           allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)
           return allowed
       }()
   }
   ```

   For more discussion on that character set, see point 2 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912606/1271826.

   Anyway, when you receive this on your server, you can retrieve it as and then reverse the base-64 encoding, and you'll have your original binary payload.
2. Alternatively, you can use `multipart/formdata` request (in which you can supply binary payload, but you have to wrap it in as part of the broader `multipart/formdata` format). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163136/1271826 if you want to do this yourself.

For both of these approaches, libraries like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) make it even easier, getting you out of the weeds of constructing these requests.

Comment: Base64 isn't really efficient, but I finally just decided text streams in http-ville were never really that efficient any way. And it's one line of code to to turn a binary Data into it's base64 version. Since I'm using it for the body, not the url, I don't even need to escape.